# Drag&Drop в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, есть ли готовый контрол или решение для WPF, которое реализует функционал перетаскивания в `TreeView`?

Нашел [только это](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55168/Drag-and-Drop-Feature-in-WPF-TreeView-Control), но там перетаскивание реализовано таким образом, что можно перетаскивать в уже готовую ветку, но нельзя вынести дочерний элемент, чтобы создалась новая ветка в корне.

Хотелось бы реализовать примерно такой же функционал как в обозревателе решений VS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Спасибо, мил человек! Очень сильно выручил!